# How to view HTML and css in IE10 debugger?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Can anyone tell me how to see the HTML/CSS source of DOM objects in Internet Explorer 10?

I want to inspect a button element on a web page debugger.

I used to click the arrow on debugger (left corner of IE debugger) and then click on button. Yet the debugger panel only shows the root tag of the web page and not the HTML/CSS of the button.

This techniques works in IE8 and IE9 on Windows 7 but not in IE10.

Can anyone suggest me any other debugger or any other solution on how to get this working?

I am using the default IE debugger.

Comment: Rephrased the question (Fixed grammar and spelling)